# Webservice gets a lot of deadlocks on new SQL Server 2014 instance

Tags: sql-server, web-services, transactionscope

We have a new database server which runs SQL Server 2014 web edition. I restored the databases which come from a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. We use a web service that imports data to the databases. The web service uses `TransactionScope`.

Against the old database server I never had troubles with it, even if 3 or 4 processes used this web service concurrently, but when I try that against our new SQL Server 2014 database, it deadlocks right away.

The thing that changed is the database server, but the settings are more or less the same.

I tried to set the isolationlevel of the transactionscope to readcommitted but that does not help..

Does anybody have a suggestion how to solve this ?

Comment: How did you restore the databases? How much data do you have? What's the status of your indexes? Is the server similarly sized? What kind of operations are the web services performing?

Comment: Also it's not a great question for StackOverflow, you might have better luck on some of the other sites in the community.

Comment: If you restored your 2008 database to a 2014 instance you need to do some unraveling. Defragment indexes, update statistics etc. There are a number of housekeeping things you need to do.

Comment: Do you have the same disks with the same IO ?

Comment: To answer the question above : you are rght Derrick, the question is maybe not a good one for this forum. It feels it is a bit in the middle between dba and developer.  Anyway I did the housekeeping when I restored the databases (rebuild indexes, map users). The webservice performs methods that insert/update and deletes on multiple tables within a transactionscope.  Rom, the server we got has 2 physicial harddrives, they are not in a raid configuration. I put the data files on the one drive and the log files on the other. I thought that would be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "feature" in the TransactionScope class where the default constructor creates connections in a SERIALIZABLE isolation level.  Unfortunately, this "feature" also causes pooled connections to leak over into SERIALIZABLE isolation level as they are not fully reset.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful

You can find out if you are running into this problem by seeing if you have sessions running in a serializable isolation level.

```
select * 
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where transaction_isolation_level = 4
```